# App not started with Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2, and Android app not installed on Android 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an app with the following Gradle setting:

```
Java 17.0.6
Gradle 7.5
Android Plugin 7.4.2
```

I have these setting in build Gradle in app folder

```
minSdk 22
targetSdk 33
```

I have two physical Android phones:

One runs on Android 10: App not started and even not installed, although it should be installed because the min SDK target is 22 in the setting.
The other runs on Android 13: App not started but installed.

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column _display_name
                                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.computeSingleProjectionOrThrow(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:1142)
                                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.computeProjection(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:1113)
```

---

- The Android SDK of the device under debug has API level 29.
- Android SDK source code for this API level cannot be found.

---

Any idea how to fix this issue of not running the app in Android Giraffe? and how to make the app installed on both Android versions.

**Solution: `android:exported="true"` fixed the problem**